# Creating admin-consent in PowerShell after app registration with Azure CLI make an error

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, registration

After I created an app I add admin-consent - but it failed on last line

```
$myApiAppRegistration = az ad app create --display-name $appName --password $secret --reply-urls $replyUrl --required-resource-accesses $resources --available-to-other-tenants false

$myApiAppRegistrationResult = ($myApiAppRegistration | ConvertFrom-Json)

az ad app permission admin-consent --id $myApiAppRegistrationResult.appId
```

[image]

If run this command in the shell - it works fine.

---

### I found the problem - sometime timeout is required.

```
Write-Host ' Create Service Principal'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
az ad sp create --id $appId
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host ' Add Permission grant'
az ad app permission grant --id $appId --api $graphId
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host ' Admin consent. AppId:'  $appId
az ad app permission admin-consent --id $appId
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem using the Azure CLI. Adding a delay between the commands was the only workaround I found as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `az account show` to make sure you logged in the correct admin account in the powershell, and try to specify the `--identifier-uris` when you creating the app.

```
$myApiAppRegistration = az ad app create --display-name $appName --password $secret --reply-urls $replyUrl --identifier-uris 'https://testapp777' --required-resource-accesses $resources --available-to-other-tenants false
```

Answer (score 0):

Before granting consent I have to:

```
-- Service Principal
az ad sp create --id $appId |Out-Null

-- Grant Permissions
az ad app permission grant --id $appId --api $graphId
```